# Автоматический переход к якорю

Tags: jquery, javascript

Доброго времени суток.

Интересует такая задача:
Есть набор якорей на странице. Нужно при попытке промотки страницы автоматически перемещать юзера к следующему якорю из массива.

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В чем сложность?

- Создать массив высот "якорей"
- Ловить событие прокрутки ("onscroll")
- Перемещать страницу к нужной высоте из массива

Comment: Если, например, скроллить вниз, то  смещается вниз. Это ясно как день. А если вверх? Вот тут и вопрос.